# A quotient module of the field of formal Laurent series

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, quotient-spaces

Let $\mathbb K:=\mathbb C((t))$ be the field of formal Laurent series. Is the quotient  $\frac{\mathbb K}{t^n\mathbb C[[t]]}$ a $\mathbb C[[t]]/t^n\mathbb C[[t]]$-module or is it only a $\mathbb C[[t]]$-module?

Comment: Does $t^n$ act as $0$?

Comment: You mean if $t^n$ annihilates $\mathbb K$? I think, no. So, you say that $\mathbb K/t^n\mathbb C[[t]]$ does not have a well-defined $\mathbb C[[t]]/t^n\mathbb C[[t]]$-structure, don't you?

Comment: Does it annihilate every element of your $\Bbb{C}[[t]]$-module $M=\Bbb{C}((t))/t^n \Bbb{C}[[t]]$. This is needed to get a $\Bbb{C}[[t]]/(t^n)$-module structure on $M$.

Comment: Right, right. However, not every element in $\mathbb C((t))/t^n\mathbb C[[t]]$ is annihilated by $t^n$. For example $t^{-1} \mod t^n\mathbb C[[t]]$ is not annihilated by $t^n$.